# Laravel: Get route by specify name

Tags: laravel, get, routes

I have config route like this:

```
Route::get(
    'index/{type?}',
    [
        'as'   => 'AAA.index',
        'uses' => 'AAA@index',
    ]
);

Route::any(
    'create/{type}',
    [
        'as'   => 'AAA.create',
        'uses' => 'AAA@create',
    ]
);
```

If I have a string **AAA.index**, I want to get **index/{type?}**

If I have a string **AAA.create**, I want to get **create/{type?}**

What is the method can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use route method:

> route('AAA.index', $parameter);

See in: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-route